# Show that a nonzero free abelian group has a subgroup of index n for every positive integer n.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that a nonzero free abelian group has a subgroup of index n for every positive integer n.  There is a similar question on here but non of the answers make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

The task is equivalent to construct a surjective homomorphism $\to \mathbb{Z}/n$. It is enough to remark that there is a surjective homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/n$ (the canonical projection) and that every nonzero free abelian group $\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus I}$ surjects onto some $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning:** The following seems to require the Axiom of Choice, which with whom I'm very comfortable, btw.

Let $\,A_\omega:=\langle\,a_i\,\rangle_{i\in I}\,$ be the free abelian group group of rank $\,|I|:=\omega\,\,,\,\omega=\text{ any ordinal}$ , and for any $\,n\in\Bbb N\,\,,\,\,C_n:=\langle c_n\,\rangle =$ the cyclic group of order $\,n\,$.

By the universal property of free abelian groups, the *set function*

$$f:\{a_i\}_{i\in I}\to C_n\,\,,\,\,f(a_{i_0}):= c_n\,\,,\,\,f(a_i)=1\,\,,\,i_0\neq i\in I$$

extends *uniquely* to a group homomorphism $\,\phi:A_\omega\to C_n\,$ . (the index $\,i_o\in I\,$ may be chosen at will)

Well, $\,\ker\phi\leq A_\omega\,$ has index $\,n\,$ ...

Comment: The argument is of courdse not restricted to finitely generated free-abelian groups ...

Comment: Of course, my bad. Thanks and I shall remove that restriction now

Comment: I think you don't need AC. That the set of subgroups of index $n$ is non-empty should follow from the fact that every element of $I$ gives rise to such a subgroup.

Comment: Not for that is AC needed but for defining the function $\,f\,$...